# combining get_absolute_url into a raw SQL statement in django

Tags: sql, django, postgresql

Am working on a django application with uses several complex queries to return ranks, ratios and other complicated output. I've followed few exampled from the web which helped me find the best way to put it and retrieve data from the query set returned

Yet, I would like to find a way to inject custom details into a given record, for example in my case, am trying to associate the get_absolute_url() value into the returned record set

Below is an example which returns the most used interests, this query will always return a limited queryset, is there a way to extend the returned dictionary with the get_absolute_url() value of the model?

```
def most_used_interests(self, limit_by=10):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""
            SELECT
                i.name,
                i.name_ar,
                i.name_en,
                ij.interest_id,
                SUM (ij.C) item_count
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT
                        C .interest_id,
                        COUNT (b. ID) C
                    FROM
                        bargain_bargain b,
                        bargain_bargain_bargain_target C
                    WHERE
                        b. ID = C .bargain_id
                    GROUP BY
                        C .interest_id
                    UNION
                        SELECT
                            x.interest_id,
                            COUNT (P . ID) C
                        FROM
                            promotion_promotion P,
                            promotion_promotion_promo_target x
                        WHERE
                            x.promotion_id = P . ID
                        GROUP BY
                            x.interest_id
                ) ij, list_interest i
            WHERE i.id=ij.interest_id
            GROUP BY
                ij.interest_id,
                i.name,
                i.name_ar,
                i.name_en
            ORDER BY
                item_count DESC
            LIMIT %s
    """, [limit_by, ])
    desc = cursor.description
    if cursor.rowcount:
        return [
            dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
            for row in cursor.fetchall()
        ]
    return None
```

Comment: You mean other than fetching and extending the column before zipping it?

Comment: yeah sort of, trying to add the get_absolute_url as they assigned to the returned dictionary

Answer (score 1):

I found an easier way to deal with the situation, for others who is facing similar problem, I wrapped my query to always return the object and then use objects.raw for the returned query

```
def most_used_interests(self, limit_by=10):
    return self.raw("""
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                list_interest l,
                (
                    SELECT
                        ij.interest_id,
                        SUM (ij. C) item_count
                    FROM
                        (
                            SELECT
                                C .interest_id,
                                COUNT (b. ID) C
                            FROM
                                bargain_bargain b,
                                bargain_bargain_bargain_target C
                            WHERE
                                b. ID = C .bargain_id
                            GROUP BY
                                C .interest_id
                            UNION
                                SELECT
                                    x.interest_id,
                                    COUNT (P . ID) C
                                FROM
                                    promotion_promotion P,
                                    promotion_promotion_promo_target x
                                WHERE
                                    x.promotion_id = P . ID
                                GROUP BY
                                    x.interest_id
                        ) ij
                    GROUP BY
                        ij.interest_id
                    LIMIT %s
                ) tl
            WHERE
                l. ID = tl.interest_id
            ORDER BY
                item_count DESC
    """, [limit_by, ]
```